# Convert milliseconds to formatted date in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, date, node-modules, datetime-format

I get a date in Milliseconds like this

> 1525520235000

and I want to convert it to local time

> Sat May 05 2018 17:22:15

How can I accomplish this in NodeJS? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List of all `get` functions are here : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

```js
let x = 1525520235000;
const mydate = new Date(x);
const month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
][mydate.getMonth()];
var day = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'][mydate.getDay()];

console.log('Day: ', day);

console.log('Month: ', month);

console.log('Year: ', mydate.getFullYear());

console.log("Hours: ", mydate.getHours());

console.log("Mitutes: ", mydate.getMinutes());

console.log(mydate.toString("MMMM yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 8):

may be this helps:

```
date = new Date(1525520235000);
date.toString();
```

the result is like:

> "Sat May 05 2018 18:37:15 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)"

Answer (score 1):

```
var moment = require('moment');

var dateTime = new Date(1525520235000);
var result = moment(dateTime).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
console.log(result);
```

for more referrences visit
https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Simple use momentjs

```js
const moment = require('moment');

var time = moment(1525520235000).format('MMMM MM YYYY h:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any external package, you can get a closer result by using [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) like as below -

```
var date = 1525520235000;
var options = { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' };
var d = new Date(date);
var ds = d.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
console.log(ds);
```

> the result is like : Sat, May 05, 2018, 11:37:15 AM

`